ADXL345 reading using STM32F103C8T6 Gives only 0
Hi i try to interface an ADXL345 using stm32f103C8T6 through SPI protocol, when i press reset button it gives some value to me but some time later it gives only 0 on all axes even when i try to move the sensor
i write the code using Keil
#include "adxl345.h"
SPI_HandleTypeDef* handler;
ADXLInitTypedef adxlconfig;


void adxl_write(uint8_t address, uint8_t value){
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
    uint8_t dataframe[2];
    uint8_t timeout = 5;
    dataframe[0] = address;
    dataframe[1] = value;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, ADXL_SW, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    status = HAL_SPI_Transmit (handler, dataframe, 2, timeout);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOB, ADXL_SW, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
    
uint8_t adxl_read(uint8_t address){
    HAL_StatusTypeDef TXstatus;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef RXstatus;
    address |= 0x80;  // read operation
    uint8_t result;
    uint8_t timeout = 5;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOB, ADXL_SW, GPIO_PIN_RESET);  // pull the pin low
    TXstatus = HAL_SPI_Transmit (handler, &address, 1, timeout);  // send address
    RXstatus = HAL_SPI_Receive (handler, &result, 6, timeout);  // receive 6 bytes data
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOB, ADXL_SW, GPIO_PIN_SET);  // pull the pin high
    if(RXstatus == HAL_OK && TXstatus == HAL_OK){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
    return result;
} 

void adxl_init(SPI_HandleTypeDef* exthandler){
    handler = exthandler;
    adxlconfig.spimode = 0x00;
    adxl_write(ADXL_DATA_FORMAT, 0x08);  // data_format range= +- 2g
    adxl_write(ADXL_FIFO_CTL, 0x80);
    adxl_write(ADXL_BW_RATE, 0x0D);
    adxl_write(ADXL_POWER_CTL, 0x00);  // reset all bits
    adxl_write(ADXL_POWER_CTL, 0x08);
}

float roundDecimal(float value){
    float factor = 100000.0f;
    float scaledValue = (value) * factor;
    int32_t roundedValue = (int32_t)roundf(scaledValue);
    value = (float)roundedValue / factor;
    return value;
}
void get_GForce(float* buffer){
    uint8_t accX0 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAX0);
    uint8_t accX1 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAX1);
    uint8_t accY0 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAY0);
    uint8_t accY1 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAY1);
    uint8_t accZ0 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAZ0);
    uint8_t accZ1 = adxl_read(ADXL_DATAZ1);
    
    int16_t x_accel = ((int16_t)accX1 << 8) | accX1;
    int16_t y_accel = ((int16_t)accY1 << 8) | accY1;
    int16_t z_accel = ((int16_t)accZ1 << 8) | accZ1;
    
    buffer[0] = roundDecimal(x_accel / ADXL345_MULTIPLIER);
    buffer[1] = roundDecimal(y_accel / ADXL345_MULTIPLIER);
    buffer[2] = roundDecimal(z_accel / ADXL345_MULTIPLIER);
}

can someone help me what happend?, this is how i call it from main.c
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
get_GForce(GForce);
stream_sendGForce(&huart1, GForce, GForce_size);

And this what i get in my serial viewer.
First run after press reset button:

Then after some time:


It will likely take someone minutes to hours to dig through the ADXL345 specs just to see if your init will work. I'd start there as there appears settings that may be missing. For instance, how often do the accelerometer sensors create new readings? Other noteworthy things:  1) Your 8 to 16 bit conversion code is wrong. 2) Where are you calibrating the sensor? (What I would do: I'd get an all STMicro sensor eval kit, start with their known good software & and work backwards from there.)

One bug is that you are using the X1 byte twice (and not the X0 byte) to form the accel word.  There may be other bugs in your conversion, printing, or transmitting code.  Look at the raw ADC values from the accelerometer to see if the accelerometer is providing zero values or whether the bug is within your conversion code.
